# how can i retrieving text from input field as its entered in JavaScript??

Tags: javascript

How can i retrieve the contents of an input field as they are entered with JavaScript?

i know .onChange only works after the focus is changed from the input field?

thanks

Comment: onblur event will fire once the focus is out of the textbox control. You can handle it in OntextChanged event

Comment: @Mo: I published a blog post on this subject today, might be an interesting read for you - http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the onKeyUp event. Here's a simple example:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML=this.value">
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

Comment: onkeyup will *only* give you the value when the key is lifted.  Holding the key down will repeat the input but the keyup event will not fire.

Comment: @Andy E: Yes, but if you use only onkeydown, the value returned from the text field will not be full. I mean the last entered character will always be missing.

Comment: not if you use a timer - see my answer and the example in it.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: since writing this answer, I learned of the HTML5 `oninput` event which is much more appropriate than key events because it will detect all forms of input including paste, drag and drop, etc.  The event is supported in all major browsers except IE 8 and lower, but you can simulate the event in IE by mapping to `onpropertychange` instead.  Example:

```
if ("onpropertychange" in myInput && !("oninput" in myInput)) {
    myInput.onpropertychange = function () {
        if (event.propertyName == "value") 
            myHandler.call(this, event);
    }
}
else
    myInput.oninput = myHandler;
```

Note that `onpropertychange` doesn't fire when inputting into non-form elements with the `contentEditable` property set.

---

*onkeyup* will only fire **after** the key is lifted, so for best results use *onkeypress* and/or *onkeydown*.  If you use a timer with a delay of 0ms, you can get the new value immediately after it is updated:

```
myInput.onkeydown = function () {
    var self = this;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        alert(self.value);
    },0);
}
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fgcYD/**

Note that this won't catch pasting or dragging and dropping text into the box.  For those you need other events.

Answer (score 1):

If your input field has focus, use the onKeyUp event to monitor the user typing text.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Answer (score 1):

Once I had used a combination of "onKeyup", "onBlur", onKeyPress to handle all the circumstances while making a TextBox to allow only numeric values. Like this:

```
//C#    
tc.Attributes.Add("onKeyup", "extractNumber(this,-1,true);"); tc.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "extractNumber(this,-1,true,true);"); tc.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "return blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, true);");
```

with this .js code:
http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/validate2.js

And it still works pretty well.